# Buttons in reactjs vs html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

hi guys i'm learning reactjs right now and I ran into something I found interesting. Until now when I wanted to make a button, I'd create it in html and write a function in js to do something with it. Well now i see i can do it all in jsx. So my question is why should I ever create a button in html again? what are the benefits one way or the other?

Comment: subjective... matter of opinion. Is there really a question here or just opinions?

Comment: JSX is basically a template language to generate HTML with. So using JSX is using HTML.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building a react js application, then you will be using JSX for your template code, not HTML. Benefits of JSX are aplenty.

JSX lets you add conditions, loops, expressions into your template code ( like the templating libraries such as handlebar, ractive etc ).

With just plain HTML if you wanted to create a list of 10 <li> elements, you will have to write 10 lines of html code for it.

But with JSX ( or any other templating library) you can use a for loop and just write one line of code to create the list. In short JSX ( or any other templating library) enables us to write re-usable, dynamic template codes which we cant do with plain HTML

You can read and learn more about it from the React JS documentation site itself.

[React handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

[Introducing JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#why-jsx)

Answer (score 1):

Well JSX is a React extension that allows us to write JavaScript that looks like HTML. When you are building a complete React application you would only write in JSX in return statements, even if it looks like HTML. React provides us a lot of tools to simplify development so that we only need JavaScript (and by extension JSX).